# Defining constant operation without resolving it at compilation time

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, operation

I have the following directive in my C code:

#define SCALE  156/10

It is used to multiply a value from a sensor.
As I work only with integers, the operation is

result = sensor * SCALE;

So, if the sensor reads 10, the correct result would be 156. But it appears as the compiler is resolving it and result value is 150. Is there any directive to tell the compiler to not optmize this particular #define?

Comment: Something's wrong here.  As you've written it, the line should be expanded as `result = sensor * 156/10`, and `*` and `/` associate left-to-right, so it would be evaluated as `result = (sensor * 156)/10` which equals `156` when `sensor == 10`.  It's not a good practice but in this special case it should do what you want.  Are you sure what you posted is the exact code from your program?  Or do you perhaps have `#define SCALE (156/10)` instead?

Comment: Relying on operator precedence is a poor way to do this, because as written you will get 156, but if you change it to `result = SCALE * sensor` you would get 150 instead, making it appear that multiplication doesn't commute.  A better approach would be to rewrite the macro with an argument and enforce the order of operations, as `#define SCALE_VALUE(x) (((x) * 156) / 10)`.  Or better yet, use an inline function instead.

Comment: Anyway, none of this has to do with compiler optimizations (unless your compiler is horrifically broken); it's solely about operator precedence and the fact that integer division truncates.  You would get the same results if the computation were done at runtime, only less efficiently.